# How to open a popover while closing an already open popover at the same time

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I already have a week-view calendar (using fullcalendar) displaying the events. When clicking an event, a popover shows just like I want it too. However, when I click another event, a new popover opens while the previous popover is still visible. Currently, I have to click on the event again to close the popover. I would like to have the previous popover close automatically once a new popover opens. Is it doable? My codes for displaying the popover is shown below. So far, I've tried a "detection mechanism" to determine if any popovers are visible then close them first before displaying a new one. I have no luck making it work, though. I also can't seem to make the suggestions from other forums (even the ones here on stackoverflow) to work.

//calendar.js

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var pcontent = "";
    pcontent += "<h5 class=semibold>";
    pcontent += "<img class='mr10' src='images/bloggingservices.png' width='42' height='42' />";
    pcontent += calEvent.title;
    pcontent += "</h5>";
    pcontent += "<hr/>";
    pcontent += "<p class=''><span class='ico-clock'></span> Time: ";
    pcontent += $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.start).format('hh:mm');
    pcontent += " - ";
    pcontent += $.fullCalendar.moment(calEvent.end).format('hh:mm');
    pcontent += "</p>";

    $('.popover.in').remove(); // adding this line works for me

    $(this).popover({
        placement: "bottom",
        html: true,
        trigger: "manual", // I already tried changing the trigger to "focus" but it didn't work
        content: pcontent
    }).popover("toggle");   


    // $(this).not(this).popover('hide');     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close all popover , except the clicked one by getting all the popover elements by using attribute selector with attribute **data-toggle="popover"** and hide all the popover except the current popover by comparing each of the element with event.target - which would have the current element clicked .

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover().on('click', function (e) {
    //select all popover in the page and loop through 
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function (i,item) {
        //compare each element with the current element 
        if(item != e.target)
            $(item).popover("hide");
    });
});
```

It's not the efficient way . Still its good for quick solution 
[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikneshwar/syeg4v9c/1/)

Comment: The events on the calendar are placed on buttons but divs. So it seems I won't be able to use your suggestions. I did manage to find a solution that fits my requirements. I placed this code, $('.popover.in').remove();, before displaying the popover.